# Run shell script after succesfull execution of parellel scripts

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 4 shell scripts, first 3 scripts i want to execute parallel. Later after successful completion of all 3 scripts i want to execute 4th script

```
Parellelexecution  
     sh script1.sh,
     sh script2.sh,
     sh script3.sh
```

script4.sh should execute after all 3 execution.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can do:

```
pids=
for s in script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh; do
   $s &
   pids="$pids $!"
done

JOBS_FAILED=false
for pid in $pids; do
   if ! wait $pid; then
       # script didn't exit successfully
       JOBS_FAILED=true
   fi
done

if [[ $JOBS_FAILED == false ]]; then
    script4.sh
fi
```

First it starts all the first 3 scripts in background and collects their pids. Then it runs through each pid waiting for it to exit and checking its return value. If any of the first three scripts fail, `$JOBS_FAILED` is set to the string `true` but all the processes are still waited on. Once all the first 3 scripts finish, the script checks if any jobs failed. If not, script4.sh is run.

Comment: Instead of exiting on the first failure, you might simply want to set a `JOB_FAILED` flag. After all the background jobs have completed, then run `script4.sh` only if `JOB_FAILED` isn't set.

Comment: @KurtStutsman Thanks everyone,  Exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

`bash` 4.3 added a `-n` flag to `wait` that lets it wait for any one background job to complete. For a fixed number of background jobs, you could do use something like

```
script1.sh &
script2.sh &
script3.sh &
wait -n && wait -n && wait -n && script4.sh
```

For a large or variable number of background jobs, Kurt's answer is better.